# gazebo7 trying to load libgazebo.so.8

Tags: gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When I try to start gazebo 7, gzserver reports an error that it can't open libgazebo.so.8. I've installed from debs on ubuntu 16.04. I have checked ldconfig and the rest of my filesystem and I can't find any trace of libgazebo8.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15391/gazebo7-trying-to-load-libgazebo.so.8/) by [ckchow](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3043/ckchow/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I imagine this is related to [this](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15384/gazebo8-depends-on-libignition-math2-and-libignition-math3-which-conflict/) question.

If you've mixed a lot of different source and deb install versions, I recommend you `apt remove` everything related to gazebo, ignition and sdformat, and `make uninstall` from the build directories. After that, dig around your `/usr` directory and delete anything related to gazebo, ignition and sdformat that you can find.

After all this you should be in a relatively clean state. But to be sure, when installing Gazebo 7 from debs, use the `--reinstall` flag:

```
sudo apt install gazebo7 --reinstall
```

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ckchow](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3043/ckchow/) on 2017-02-09**:
I figured out that the busted source installs that I had done had created bad versions of gzclient and gzserver that were linked to libgazebo8. I had tried `make uninstall`, and it would probably have gotten rid of gzserver and friends, but the make commands were all broken because I had uninstalled libignition and some other dependencies already.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-02-09**:
Glad you solved the problem. This kind of thing happens to me all the time.